Cross-Validation Visualization Mulfunctions
I am inspired by the scikit-learn's cross-validation visuailization guide to visuailize the distribution of training and testing indicies in each CV split:
cmap_data = plt.cm.Paired
cmap_cv = plt.cm.coolwarm
def plot_cv_indices(cv, X, y, group, ax, n_splits, lw=10):
    """Create a sample plot for indices of a cross-validation object."""

    # Generate the training/testing visualizations for each CV split
    for ii, (tr, tt) in enumerate(cv.split(X=X, y=y, groups=group)):
        # Fill in indices with the training/test groups
        indices = np.array([np.nan] * len(X))
        indices[tt] = 1
        indices[tr] = 0

        # Visualize the results
        ax.scatter(
            range(len(indices)),
            [ii + 0.5] * len(indices),
            c=indices,
            marker="_",
            lw=lw,
            cmap=cmap_cv,
            vmin=-0.2,
            vmax=1.2,
        )

    # Plot the data classes and groups at the end
    ax.scatter(
        range(len(X)), [ii + 1.5] * len(X), c=y, marker="_", lw=lw, cmap=cmap_data
    )

    ax.scatter(
        range(len(X)), [ii + 2.5] * len(X), c=group, marker="_", lw=lw, cmap=cmap_data
    )

    # Formatting
    yticklabels = list(range(n_splits)) + ["class", "group"]
    ax.set(
        yticks=np.arange(n_splits + 2) + 0.5,
        yticklabels=yticklabels,
        xlabel="Sample index",
        ylabel="CV iteration",
        ylim=[n_splits + 2.2, -0.2],
        xlim=[0, 100],
    )
    ax.set_title("{}".format(type(cv).__name__), fontsize=15)
    plt.show()

from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit, KFold

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 5))
X, y = make_classification(
    n_samples=1000,
    n_features=10,
    n_informative=3,
    n_redundant=0,
    n_repeated=0,
    n_classes=2,
    random_state=42,
    shuffle=False,
)
plot_cv_indices(
    TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=5, gap=10),
    X=X,
    y=y,
    group=None,
    ax=ax,
    n_splits=5,
)

The above code gives me:

I am looking for:

The idea of the expected plot is that the graph successfully visuailizes the gaps between the training and testing sets in each split. In addition, I ran a test case on the normal KFold as well the plot_cv_indices function does not seem to operate properly even then.
